# Same Guava rateLimiter not able to work with multiple methods

Tags: spring, spring-boot, guava

I am trying to implemt RateLimiter using guava.

Below is my class where I have added RateLimiter. I wanted to rate Limit method-xyzMethod present in service class. I have made qps/tps as 3 for rateLimiter. When I see the time stamp at which method xyzMethod is called it seems it is not rate limited to 3  which what I set.  Can anyone help me achieve it.

```
@Service
class Service{ 
 private  RateLimiter rateLimiter;

  @Autowired
  public void setRateLimiter(RateLimiter rateLimiter) {
    this.rateLimiter = rateLimiter;
  }

public method1(){

rateLimiter.acquire();
System.out.println(new Date() + ": Beep");
xyzMethod();

}

public method2(){

rateLimiter.acquire();
System.out.println(new Date() + ": Beep");
xyzMethod();

}

public method3(){

rateLimiter.acquire();
System.out.println(new Date() + ": Beep");
xyzMethod();

}

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class RatelimiterConfig {

  @Value("${tps}")
  private int tps;

  @Bean
  public RateLimiter rateLimiter(){
    return  RateLimiter.create(tps);
  }
}
```

application.yml

```
tps: 3
```

Added below dependency

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>32.0.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What timestamp information do you get?